# how to capitalize first letter of every word without .capitalize or .upper or .title in python

Tags: python, string

I currently have:

```
def myTitle(string):
    index = 0
    title = ''
    while index < len(string):
        if string[index] == ' ':
            upper=string[index+1]
            upper = (ord(upper) - 32)
            title = title + ' ' + chr(upper)
        else:
            title = title + string[index]
```

String is defined as "I like coffee a lot" but title gets returned as "I Llike Ccoffee Aa Llot"

Answer (score 1):

You've just forgotten 3 lines:
`index+=1` twice and `return title`

The fixed function looks like this:

```
def myTitle(string):
    index = 0
    title = ''
    while index < len(string):
        if string[index] == ' ':
            upper=string[index+1]
            upper = (ord(upper) - 32)
            title = title + ' ' + chr(upper)
            index+=1
        else:
            title = title + string[index]
        index+=1
    return title
```

Comment: oops, thanks for pointing that out! It seems I still get the same result though. Instead of "I Like Coffee A Lot" I get "I Llike Ccoffee Aa Llot". Any tips on how to fix that?

Comment: If you copy & paste my function you won't get those double letters. They appear because you don't move on after adding the upper case letter.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I just wasn't indenting correctly